# How to copy specific files from setup project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, setup-project

I created installer with setup project in visual studio 2008.

I added 2 [folders](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/0tQ80la_UZVctefF4vIXytMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink) (win32 & win64) with files to setup project. I want the files from win32 or win64 be placed to specific directory inside Application folder depending on CPU architecture.
By default both folders are placed into Application folder, but what I should do so only the files from specific folder will be copied?

Comment: What do you have in win32 and 64 folders ? same dlls built for different architecture ? 32 and 64 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you can simply enter the property name **VersionNT64** as the `Condition` for including the file you want for 64 bit. I would guess you can use `Not` for the opposite.

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa372497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).